# Zip Archive: Can I rename or move a ZipArchiveEntry?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Does the .NET ZipArchive allow to rename or move entries? Currently it's not possible to change the name of a ZipArchiveEntry once it is created. It seems that I have to copy the stream of the original ZipArchiveEntry to a newly ZipArchiveEntry with the changed name.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know what "move" would mean, other than to rename an entry. Even in regular disk file systems, a "move" really is just a rename where the full path of the file name has changed, not just the "leaf node" file name. In a .zip archive, this is even more explicit; a "directory" or "folder" in an archive exists only by virtue of an entry having that directory name in its name (separated, of course, by a directory separator character). So "move" is exactly the same as "rename".

As far as whether you can rename things, no…with [`ZipArchive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx), you will have to create a new entry that is a copy of the original, but with the new name, and then delete the original.

Code to do that would look like this:

```
static void RenameEntry(this ZipArchive archive, string oldName, string newName)
{
    ZipArchiveEntry oldEntry = archive.GetEntry(oldName),
        newEntry = archive.CreateEntry(newName);

    using (Stream oldStream = oldEntry.Open())
    using (Stream newStream = newEntry.Open())
    {
        oldStream.CopyTo(newStream);
    }

    oldEntry.Delete();
}
```

Implemented as an extension method, as above, you can call like this:

```
ZipArchive archive = ...; open archive in "update" mode
string oldName = ...,
    newName = ...; // names initialized as appropriate

archive.RenameEntry(oldName, newName);
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. IO was expecting this. I was only hoping there might be some more elegant way with having to copy the data. But if not this solution is fine for me.

Comment: @MdAslam: If your call to Close() doesn't return immediately, you have a bug. Sample code isn't going to help. You need to debug the code, or post a new question asking for help (making sure to provide a good [mcve])